# how can i fire a point to the end of the screen in opengl?

Tags: opengl, 2d, glut

How can I fire a point from a shape in the middle of a 2d screen toward the mouse cursor, such that it continues to the edge of the screen?

```
void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
  if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
  {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2i(x,y);

    glFlush();
  }
}
```

Here is an image of a point moving toward the mouse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVdqr.png

Comment: Is there any particular problem with this code sample? If not, then leave it away.

Comment: For each `glBegin`, there should be a matching `glEnd`

Comment: Based on the attached picture, this seems to be a homework assignment.  What have you tried?  Are you having trouble with the OpenGL programming part, or the math for calculating the vector?

Comment: @MobyDisk i do not have w problem with the math i can not get the idea of moving the point in the direction of the mouse

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the direction in which the particle has to fly, which is given by

```
d = normalize(MousePos - ScreenCenter)
```

In each frame you update your point's position by adding the direction (most probably times a factor controlling the speed) to it:

```
PointPos = PointPos + d * speed
```

When you reach the borders of your screen you make the point disappear. Testing whether you left the visible area should be straight-forward by testing the PointPos against minimum and maximum of your screen.